# Change bullet style / formatting in Beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, formatting, enumerate, itemize

I like the Boadilla layout for Beamer presentations, but I find its `enumerate` bullet points illegible, as illustrated below (from the [Beamer Theme Matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/)).

[image: Boadilla bullet points]

How can I change the formatting of the bullet points in the `enumerate` environment to something more legible, like the default style, illustrated below?

[image: default bullet points]

Is it possible to borrow a different style's bullet point formatting, either in whole, or in parts (`itemize` and `enumerate` separately)?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
```

See section 12.1 of the [manual of beamer](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for more information.

Comment: This is cool, but it seems not to change the TOC items. Also, it'd be good to include a section number for the manual, cause that's one dense document.

Comment: Also, `items` is the parent of both enumerate and itemize items, so you can just do something like `\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]`, and it will apply to both.

Answer (score 23):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{boadilla}

% Adapted from beamerinnerthemedfault.sty
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\insertenumlabel.}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\insertenumlabel.\insertsubenumlabel}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subsubitem}{\insertenumlabel.\insertsubenumlabel.\insertsubsubenumlabel}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate mini template}{\insertenumlabel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item{bla}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item{blubb}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item{foo}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's right, but not the common use.

Comment: @Leo Liu: I suspected so, and only posted my answer because the original version of your one didn't seem to work.

Comment: You're right. I misused braces (should be bracets).

Answer (score 15):

You can use inner theme constructs to achieve a uniform style. For instance, when I prefer to use square face for items, sections and subsections, I would use the following.

```
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
```

Please [browse the beamer source code](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/tree/master/base/themes) for various themes to get an idea about available inner themes and how various themes define certain styles. I felt that this way was easier to find what I was looking for to customize instead of reading the beamer manual.

Comment: This is excellent!

Answer (score 2):

Abstraction of Properties in Beamer

**\defbeamertemplate**{*element id*}{*option id*}[*argument index*][*default optional arg*]{*...definition...*}

**Beamer's Technique**: Give everything a label (or unique id) and apply things by referring to their label/id.

Equivalent words for ids in beamer jargon from my experience

- template
- alias

Enumerated List Template Definitions

```
\defbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{circle}{...definition...}
\defbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{circle}{...definition...}
\defbeamertemplate{enumerate subsubitem}{circle}{...definition...}
\defbeamertemplate{enumerate mini template}{circle}{...definition...}
```

To make formatting easier, all of those levels can be abstracted into one object we can call a parent with

```
\defbeamertemplateparent{enumerate items}{enumerate item,enumerate subitem,enumerate subsubitem,enumerate mini template}{}
```

It is also possible to abstract the hell out of the layers again by assigning an alias to the whole thing, but this is not done for enumerated lists:

```
\defbeamertemplatealias{itemize item}{triangle}{default}
\defbeamertemplatealias{itemize subitem}{triangle}{default}
\defbeamertemplatealias{itemize subsubitem}{triangle}{default}
```

## Example of Defaults for Enumerated

As you can see, there is no formatting, just numbering. This is why using ``''

```
\defbeamertemplate*{enumerate item}{default}{\insertenumlabel.}
\defbeamertemplate*{enumerate subitem}{default}{\insertenumlabel.\insertsubenumlabel}
\defbeamertemplate*{enumerate subsubitem}{default}{\insertenumlabel.\insertsubenumlabel.\insertsubsubenumlabel}
\defbeamertemplate*{enumerate mini template}{default}{\insertenumlabel}
```

## Example Using fontawesome as Bullet

Makes the bullet a right-facing chevron in itemized lists.

```
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{chevron}{\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}\raise1.25pt\hbox{\faAngleRight}}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[chevron]
```

## Boadilla

```
texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerthemeBoadilla.sty
```

It just imports another inner theme, which controls aspects of the content of slides. 
It loads rounded. Without looking into the details of rounded, I can guess from the semantics of the name
that that is ther reason for the ugly enumerated balls.