# different itemize lists within the same itemize list in beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize

In beamer, how to use different itemize styles within same itemize list. I'm keep on getting only the bullet lists. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use one of the predefined styles with `\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[...]` or use whatever symbol you want in `\item[..]`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item test
    {
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
    \item test
    }
    \item[whatever] test
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\custom{\tikz \draw[line width=0.2mm,blue,-,fill=orange](0,0)--(3pt,3pt)--(6pt,0)--cycle;}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item[\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}] Item 1.
    \item[\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}] Item 2
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
  \item Item 3
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
  \item Item 4
        \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
  \item Item 5
  \item[\custom] Item 6
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I used this question's first answers too:
[Change bullet style / formatting in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11168/120578)